# Subset only rows containing complete cases from list of matrices

Tags: arrays, r, list, matrix, na

I have a list of matrices, all of equal dimensions. Each matrix within the list represents a different specimen; each matrix contains three columns for X, Y and Z coordinates, and each row represents a different point in 3D space (i.e., an identifiable landmark).

Most specimens are missing coordinate data for particular landmarks (so that all three columns contain NAs). I would like to subset all matrices in the list so that they only include landmarks/rows containing complete data (i.e., no NAs exist in that row for any of the specimens/matrices in the entire list).

I fear this may be quite a complicated task for data stored in list format. As all the matrices have the same dimensions, would it be easier to convert the data to an array? I wanted to avoid doing this as it would (I believe) strip the row, column and list-element names I use to identify the data.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please  read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to know how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, using `complete.cases`:

```
res <- lapply(your_list,function(mat)
                   mat[complete.cases(mat),]
```

An if your matrices, have the same number of columns, you can put the result in a big matrix using something like:

```
do.call(rbind,res)
```

Comment: Thanks; this is nearly what I wanted. While this removes every row with NAs, matrices may now have different lengths. If one matrix contains a row of missing data, the equivalent row needs to be removed from all the other matrices, too. Is this possible?

Comment: I asked this as a separate question because I figured it was a different problem, and would be of more general interest. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612625/retain-only-rows-present-in-all-matrices

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is first use

```
do.call(rbind,res)
```

then with a single matrix containing all list sub matrices add one more column  And one more column to label the rows of each sub matrix. So if your your sub matrices  has 3 rows each, the this column will look like: 1,2,3,1,2,3,...,1,2,3
 e.g

```
    singleMatrix=do.call(rbind,res)
```

rowindex=rep(c(1:numberOfRowsOfSubMatrix,numberOfSubMatrices)
Then form a combined data frame with the `indicator`, `singMatrix` and `rowindex`

```
Matrix=data.frame(singleMatrix,indicator,rowindex)
```

Now if `indicator==0` delete the row and delete all rows with thesame `rowindex` number.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with this approach is that each matrix can have a different number of rows depending on the incidence of NAs (which varies from matrix to matrix). Furthermore, where does 'indicator' come from?