# Retain only rows present in all matrices

Tags: r, list, matrix, subset

Suppose one has a list of matrix objects of different lengths, but some row names in common. How could one retain only those rows present in all matrices? I.e., starting with this:

```
> my.list

$matrix.a
        X1  X2  X3
row.A   59  36  9
row.B   54  29  44
row.C   59  36  9
row.D   54  88  32

$matrix.b
        X1  X2  X3
row.B   47  12  2
row.C   11  36  9
row.D   54  23  99

$matrix.c
        X1  X2  X3
row.A   95  31  77
row.B   63  29  44
row.C   60  43  2
```

And producing this:

```
> my.list.subsetted

$matrix.a
        X1  X2  X3
row.B   54  29  44
row.C   59  36  9

$matrix.b
        X1  X2  X3
row.B   47  12  2
row.C   11  36  9

$matrix.c
        X1  X2  X3
row.B   63  29  44
row.C   60  43  2
```

I suspect that one could use `subset()` and the `%in%` operator but I can't seem to find the exact solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
r <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(my.list, rownames))
my.list.subsetted <- lapply(my.list, function(m) m[r, ])
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is on the right track---but isn't the first line of code missing the y= argument? I get the error `Error in as.vector(y) : argument "y" is missing, with no default`.

I tried `r <- Map(intersect, lapply(my.list, rownames), lapply(my.list, rownames))` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Oops, that should be Reduce, not Map.

Comment: Thanks, but that first line now seems to simply output "`character(0)`".

Comment: @roger - it works fine for me.  Double-check two things: that `rownames(my.list$matrix.a)` returns the names (ditto for the other matrices) and that the rownames are exactly the same -- no extraneous whitespace, etc.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, you're absolutely right. I didn't realise that my data actually don't share any rows in common across all matrices! Thanks, Hong Ooi.